# Java - Need to change a date string to a date, but apply offset

Tags: java, android, time, offset

I have a date string that looks like this:

```
"2018-04-12T21:25:28.0000000-0700"
```

I need to convert this to a Date object but it needs to apply the -7 offset so that the time is

```
2:25:28 pm
```

instead of

```
9:25:28 pm
```

is there an easy way to do this?

I tried:

```
String dateString = "2018-04-12T21:25:28.0000000-0700";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

but I get:

```
date = 12/04/2018 9:25:28 PM

not 
date = 12/04/2018 2:25:28 PM
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: That `-0700` (better formatted as -07:00) means the time-of-day and date shown represent a moment seven hours behind UTC, such as seen in `America/Los_Angeles` time zone. So subtracting seven hours makes no sense at all. If you want to see the same moment as UTC, *add* seven hours, not subtract.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a [comment by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807175/java-need-to-change-a-date-string-to-a-date-but-apply-offset#comment86629994_49807175), you need to *add* 7 hours to get UTC/GMT time, not subtract 7 hours. The shown offset is the offset *already* applied to the time, not the offset to apply to get UTC time. Read it as "at offset -7 hours".

Using Java 8 Time API, you do it like this:

```
String dateString = "2018-04-12T21:25:28.0000000-0700";

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ");
LocalDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, fmt)
                                       .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                                       .toLocalDateTime();

System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")));
```

*Output*

`2018-04-13 04:25:28 AM`

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using terribly troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
String input = "2018-04-12T21:25:28.0000000-0700";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX"  );
```

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime` given that your input has an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-04-12T21:25:28-07:00

### Understand offset-from-UTC

You asked “to apply the -7 offset”. You may be misunderstanding the meaning of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by your input string. That "minus seven" offset of `-0700` (better formatted with a colon as `-07:00`) means the date and time shown represent a moment seven hours behind UTC. This offset is used by several time zones such as `America/Los_Angeles` . There is no need to apply anything, as the offset is already "applied". This string means 9 PM in the evening on the 12th of April 2018 on the west coast of North America.

Perhaps what you really want is the same moment seen as UTC. In that case, you need to *add* seven hours, not subtract. **Do not read a ISO 8601 string as an equation.** A negative number means *behind* UTC, so *add* the same number of hours-minutes to get to UTC.

Furthermore, you need not do any math at all. For a UTC value, extract a `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-04-13T04:25:28Z

The `Z` on the end of an ISO 8601 string is short for `Zulu` and means UTC. so we can see that 4 AM on the following day in UTC happens at the very same time as 9 PM on the west coast of North America. In other words, 9 PM in Los Angeles is simultaneously 4 AM on the following date in Iceland and the Azores and in other places with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set a `TimeZone` to the `SimpleDateFormat`. I would advise to set `GMT` as the `TimeZone` -

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

This should return you the expected value : `Thu Apr 12 14:25:28 PDT 2018`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Your given formatting pattern does not fit the data seen in the Question.

Comment: `Thu Apr 12 14:25:28 PDT 2018` is not the correct result. And yes, your code gave that result when I ran it, so it’s incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Parse your date string into two strings thr date and the offset then subtract the offset from the date.

Comment: It could work, but it’s the complicated and error-prone way.